# Nunit Get Tests Names in a fixture

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-assembly

I wanted to ask is there a way to get all the tests' names in the TestFixturesetup where i get all the tests names and put them in a list of strings for example??

I've tried this solution but it didn't work with me and i can't solve the error it gives to me which is

> Access is denied in loading the assembly

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("E:/Visual Studio 2013/Tests_Names/Tests_Names/bin/Debug/Tests_Names.dll");


        // Foreach public class that is a TestFixture and not Ignored
      foreach (var c in a.GetTypes()
               .Where(x => x.IsPublic
               && (x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute)).Count() > 0)
               && (x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NUnit.Framework.IgnoreAttribute)).Count() == 0)))
        {

                // For each public method that is a Test and not Ignored
                foreach (var m in c.GetMethods()
                                   .Where(x => x.IsPublic
                                   && (x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute)).Count() > 0)
                                   && (x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NUnit.Framework.IgnoreAttribute)).Count() == 0)))
                {

                    // Print out the test name
                    Tests_Names.Add(m.Name);
                    // Alternately, print out the command line to run test case using nunit-console
                    //Console.WriteLine("nunit-console /run:{0}.{1} {2}", c.ToString(), m.Name, assemblyName);
                }

        }
```

Comment: What is "E:/Visual Studio 2013/Tests_Names/Tests_Names/Properties/"? It should be an assembly, so probably a .dll file.

Comment: i solved this.. is there a way to get the testfixture class name also ??

Comment: i need to get the tests' names of a certain testfixture

Comment: Replace the **Tests_Names.Add(methodInfo.Name);** with **Tests_Names.Add(string.Concat(type.Name, " - ", methodInfo.Name));** This will include the name of the class containing the test in Tests_Names list. This does not necessarily mean the classes have the TestFixture attribute. If you need to know that for sure you can call GetCustomAttributes on the type variable (like you do on the methodInfo) using typeof(TestFixtureAttribute)

Comment: excuse me littleDebugger, but this is not what i want. I want to get only certain tests for a certain class. Even to make it more simpler, i need to get the tests within this class. is there a way ?

Comment: note, i changed the function that loads the assembly and makes sure it's a testfixture attribute. how to make sure to get only the tests of this class. cause the dll loads all the tests of all the classes in the project

Comment: Add another predicate to your first Where().  && x.Name == "{name of the class}".

Comment: thank you so much @LittleDebugger !  it worked :)

Comment: This is OK to do for an adhoc use of some kind but it's extremely fragile. NUnit has lots of ways that tests are identified and duplicating it's internal logic would require a lot of work - plus you might have to update the solution for every new release of NUnit.

Comment: A more general solution might be to ask the NUnit engine to list tests for you... but if all you want to do is run them, why not just ask NUnit to do it?

Comment: no charlie i want to do something for reporting where i get to know the test cases' names, it's something not related to testing actually. i just need to print the test cases' names with their messages whether success or fail in an excel file :).